# How to enable/disable staticwebsite on blob service using script

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

In order to programmatically automate enablement of the static website on blob service. What should be the property field allowed? I am unable to find something similar to this `Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobService/staticWebsite`.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, you can do so with some Azure CLI commands.

```
# To query the current status of the property
az storage blob service-properties show --account-name <your-storage-account> --query 'staticWebsite.enabled'
```

To set toggle the `staticWebsite.enabled` property, you can use the [az storage blob service-properties update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob/service-properties?view=azure-cli-latest#az_storage_blob_service_properties_update) command as follows:

```
az storage blob service-properties update --account-name <your-storage-account> --static-website
```

The Azure PowerShell equivalents for the above would be the [Enable-AzStorageStaticWebsite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/enable-azstoragestaticwebsite?view=azps-5.8.0) and [Disable-AzStorageStaticWebsite cmdlets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/disable-azstoragestaticwebsite?view=azps-5.8.0).

Comment: There are options available using powershell and cli but i am still trying to find similar property which will be used while writing using azure policy.

Comment: @mikeknows Could you please elaborate your requirement a little?

Comment: i am trying to disable the staticwebsite by using azurepolicy but i dont find similar property   "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/staticWebsite .in order to do that how do i write my policy condition

Comment: @mikeknows `staticWebsite.enabled` is a part of [BlobServiceProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.storage/storageaccounts/blobservices?tabs=json#blobservicepropertiesproperties-object) and not exposed as an alias in Azure Policy yet, AFAIK. Please request for it here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-policy/issues